# Optimising a transform of image with a given function using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to transform a given image from a given coordinate to a coordinate on a given image.
I've written an example code using ImageDraw, but with size being 2000 it is too slow for my purpose.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
size = [size]
img = Image.new('RGB', (size,size), color = (255,200,100))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
pix = [pixel data]
for X in range(0,size):
    for Y in range (0,size):
        draw.point((X, Y), fill=pix[functionX(X),functionY(Y)])
```

I'm sure it could be done using PIL's funcions faster that my code.

Comment: `pix = [pixel data]`??

Comment: I can't tell from your code what you are really trying to do. Can you add input and expected output images please? And fill in the missing details in your code. Thanks.